# Java JTable with JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I'm trying to place a JComboBox inside a certain column of a JTable.
I have this code, and it is working:

```
    model = new DefaultTableModel();
    JComboBox<String> optionComboCell = new JComboBox<String>();
    optionComboCell.addItem("Option 1");
    optionComboCell.addItem("Option 2");
    optionComboCell.setSelectedIndex(1);


    table = new JTable(model);
    // Adding here all the columns, removed for clarity
    model.addColumn("Options");
    TableColumn optionsColumn = table.getColumn("Options");
    optionsColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(optionComboCell));
```

My problem with this, is that it doesn't show as JComboBox until a cell in that column is selected.
When the JFrame is loaded, the whole table looks the same, as if all the cells where only text.
When clicked, it shows the combo box's arrow and options, but again when deselected, it looks like a regular cell.

Any way to get around that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use a JComboBox to render your cells:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class Test4 {

    private static class ComboBoxCellRenderer extends JComboBox implements TableCellRenderer {

        public ComboBoxCellRenderer(int column) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                addItem("Cell (" + i + "," + column + ")");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setSelectedItem(value);
            return this;
        }
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.add(getTable());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Component getTable() {
        Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                row.add("Cell (" + i + "," + j + ")");
            }
            data.add(row);
        }
        Vector<String> columns = new Vector<String>();
        columns.add("Column 1");
        columns.add("Column 2");
        columns.add("Column 3");
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        int i = 0;
        Enumeration<TableColumn> c = table.getColumnModel().getColumns();
        while (c.hasMoreElements()) {
            TableColumn column = c.nextElement();
            column.setCellRenderer(new ComboBoxCellRenderer(i));
            i++;
        }
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        return scroll;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test4().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It kinda works. I've used your ComboBoxCellRenderer class, and it now shows up like a combo box, however, once an option is selected, it still appears like an empty combobox. only when the drop down list is open, the selected item is visible

Comment: @Lablabla You have to make sure that the item you are trying to select (during the call to  `getTableCellRendererComponent`) actually exists in the ComboBox model, otherwise it does not work.

Comment: Thanks. A smalle followup, How do I set the default value? Because at first, no option is shown as selected. only when I select one

Comment: @Lablabla a default value does not really make sense in this context. Everytime getTableCellRenderer is called, you need to select an item. Do you understand properly how table rendering works in Swing? It is the exact same combobox that is reused for all the different cells, hence setting a default value does not make sense as the previous cell that renderered may have changed the selected item.

Comment: Maybe default wasn't the correct word. What I meant by 'default' was the initial value when the table is loaded. when the application starts.

Comment: @Lablabla I am not sure I quite follow what you mean then (maybe it will be easier to post another question explaining what you are trying to achieve). Values of the table are at all time taken from the TableModel. Your cell renderer should provide some way to reflect properly those values (`null` is just another acceptable value). So in the method getTableCellRendererComponent, make sure that your combobox reflects properly the `value` parameter, that's all it should do. If you need to modify the data displayed by the table, then you should do it through the TableModel.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to define your own renderer for displaying components on your table, since CellEditors are only needed for editing the value within a tablecell (which is why it only reacts, when you click on a cell).

Maybe have a look at [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to learn more about the concept of renderers and editors for JTables.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the cell renderer as well.

Comment: please two or three sentences, your answer is too short, because, (last week) there is/are  ***otic user(s) that flagging shorts or another non standard post, potentially could be deleted