# Add a JCombo column to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

This type of post has been dealt with before, but I am having issues based on how my code is structured.

I am just simply trying to add a JComboBox to all rows in my last column. The code is below.

```
//Return Person objects from a method
ArrayList<Person> people = getPersonList();

String[] columnNames {"Name", "Age", "English Speaker?" };

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);

JTable table = new JTable(model);

//Create JComboBox for last column (English Speaker?)                       
JComboBox<Integer> englishCombo = new JComboBox<>();

int count = 1;

//For loop to add each Person to there rows
//Also add a boolean value to determine check box
for(Person p: people)
{
    boolean english =false;

    if(p.isEnglishSpeaker() == true)
    {
        english = true;
    }
    else
    {
        english = false;
    }
    questionCombo.addItem(count);

    model.addRow(new Object[]{p.getName(), p.getAge(), english);
}

//Get 3rd column (English Speaker)
TableColumn englishColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
//Add JComboBox to English Speaker
englishColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(englishCombo));
```

When I run this code, it only displays true of false in the 3rd column, not the JcomboBox?
Could anyone identify the problem? 
Thanks much appreciated

Comment: `boolean english =false;

    if(p.isEnglishSpeaker() == true)
    {
        english = true;
    }
    else
    {
        english = false;
    }` can also be written: `boolean english = p.isEnglishSpeaker();`. Or even simpler, drop everything written before and simply call: `model.addRow(new Object[]{p.getName(), p.getAge(), p.isEnglishSpeaker());`

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226926/java-jtable-with-jcombobox/11227034#11227034).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just changed to that easier way (dont know how I missed that). But it still returns only true of false, not the actual JComboBox? Thanks

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699467/add-different-combobox-for-each-row-of-a-column-in-a-jtable/13703143#13703143)

Comment: Read the JTable API. Follow the link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables`, where you will find a working example. Start with the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified a custom [editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender); now you need to address the [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). I see two possibilities:

1. Use `JComboBox<String>` with the desired `true` and `false` values, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356518/230513).

   [image: image1]
2. Use the default renderer and editor, `JCheckBox`, for values whose type is `Boolean.class`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528604/230513).

[image: image2]

Comment: Thanks alot for you answer. It was my mistake. I meant I needed a JCheckBox, not a JComboBox. But its the exact same approach when adding a JCheckBox, right?

Comment: `JCheckBox` is even easier, as that's the default for `TableModel` values of type `Boolean.class`. The second example under point 2. above shown how to override `getColumnClass()`.